# Getting @google-cloud/translate API to work on localhost

Tags: google-api, localhost, google-translate

Could I please get some assistance and step by step sequence of actions of what needs to be done and the conditions which need to be met to get this service to work.

My project requires translation of text. I have followed the documentation to include the following code on the Node.js server

```
const {TranslationServiceClient} = require('@google-cloud/translate');

const translationClient = new TranslationServiceClient();

async function translateText() {
  const request = {
    parent: `projects/${projectId}/locations/${location}`,
    contents: [text],
    mimeType: 'text/plain', // mime types: text/plain, text/html
    sourceLanguageCode: 'en',
    targetLanguageCode: 'sr-Latn',
  };

  const [response] = await translationClient.translateText(request);

  for (const translation of response.translations) {
    console.log(`Translation: ${translation.translatedText}`);
  }
}

translateText();
```

But of course the first stumbling block of the documentation is the failure to cater for those using ES6 imports (or whatever you call it) so used the following line instead at the top

`import {TranslationServiceClient} from '@google-cloud/translate/build/src/v3/index.js'`

which, thankfully, seems to work. Now to test it and...

```
Google translate error: Error: Could not load the default credentials. Browse to https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started for more information.
```

Now I'm reading the cobweb of documentation and navigating around my Cloud Dashboard and arriving at some comculsion that I should install Google Cloud CLI, which I do and follow the instructions that present themselves, as well as what is suggested in the docs.

There was also some mention of an `authnetication_somthing_something` environemnt variable in a `json` file a `%appdata%/gcloud/something` folder but I don't even have the `gcloud` folder. Do I have to manually create the folder and its children and create the file? I suspect not, but who knows?

Ah, but then I read more and it seems `v2` might be enough for my purposes (unless `v3` is better for all use cases?), so I go back to what I had before (although changing the `require` line they have in the documentation to `import {Translate} from '@google-cloud/translate/build/src/v2/index.js'`), hoping that  with the CLI authentication stuff I had done would grant me access but, no, I have a response with `"message": "The request is missing a valid API key."` in the body.

V2 does work on the public server, but it would be nice to have it function on localhost too. Thank you!

Comment: Load the JSON certificate by adding the line:
process.env.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS = "./cert/secret*secret*secret.json"
Add the name of the project:
parent: `projects/%PROJECT_NAME%/locations/global` and run.

Comment: Thanks. Can you tell me where I find or create this directory tree `projects/%PROJECT_NAME%/locations/global`?

Comment: That's your project name on Google Cloud.

Comment: sure, that I get, but I mean the whole thing - `/projects/`. What and where are projects? And even `/secretsecretsecret.json` doesn't make sense. Is that  json file I name with my authkey, or something? I find that hard to imagine.